# Can't use Angular-UI bootstrap typehead: JSON with multiple attributes

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "Unidades": [
    {
        "Nome": "laskjdhflksjfg",
        "Codigo": "11106600"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "wertwertwertwer",
        "Codigo": "11106601"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "wertwertwertwer",
        "Codigo": "11106602"
    }
    ]
}
```

and I'm trying to use Angular-UI bootstrap typehead doing this:

**CONTROLLER**

```
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selected = undefined;    
    $scope.url = 'unidades/unidades-controler.asp'; //the response of json is from here
    $http.get($scope.url).success(function (data, status) { 
            $scope.Unidades = data[0].Unidades;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.response = 'Request failed';
        });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div  ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">        
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="Unidade.Codigo as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in Unidades | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">        
</div>
```

My problem is: I need that `<pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>` shows `Unidade.Codigo` value, and I need that `<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="Unidade.Codigo as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in Unidades | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">` Shows `Unidade.Nome` value. How do I do that?

This is what I got:

[image]

And this is what I need:

[image]

I made this changes by following this example plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ibIMDNmK26E4mTdDK5dD?p=preview, but still not working:

**HTML**

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <pre>Model: {{Selected| json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="Selected" typeahead="Unidade.Codigo as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in getUnidades($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selected = undefined;    
    $scope.url = 'unidades/unidades-controler.asp'; //the response of json is from here
    $http.get($scope.url).success(function (data, status) { 
        $scope.Unidades = data[0].Unidades;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.response = 'Request failed';
    });
    $scope.getUnidades = function($viewValue) {
        return $http.get($scope.Unidades).then(function(response){
          return data;
        });
      };
}
```

**ERROR**

```
GET http://localhost/[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[…t],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object],[object%20Object] 400 (Bad Request)
```

I have also tried doing this:

```
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selected = undefined;    
    $scope.url = 'unidades/unidades-controler.asp'; //the response of json is from here
    $scope.getUnidades = function($viewValue) {
        return $http.get($scope.url).success(function (data, status) { 
            return data;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $scope.response = 'Request failed';
        }); 
    };
}
```

But I receive this error:

```
ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

Comment: What exactly do you want and what are you getting? I don't seem to understand the problem

Comment: I edited and put an image of what I got here.

Comment: `response` is `undefined` in the success callback there's only `data` and `status` but no response

Comment: @dcodesmith I made this change (edited right Now) but still not working...

Comment: What you have in your plunkr seems to work for me

Comment: @dcodesmith, it works but it is not doing what i need. It is doing like in the images.

Comment: Where is the code for the images then?

Comment: @dcodesmith They are before the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did, and worked.

```
    <div  ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">        
        <pre>Model: {{selected.Codigo | json}}</pre>
        <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="Unidade as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in Unidades | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">        
    </div>
```

I just changed the `typehead` to `Unidade as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in Unidades` and inside the model I'm using only what I need: `selected.Codigo`

Thank you all!

Comment: It's a good approach, but I don't understand why this works and the other way don't. I'll investigate some when on my pc.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the functionality you are asking for here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1Sm17103S73nJbpb2PmK?p=preview

It works for me with the same code you have, what exactly is what you need?

Comment: I need what you show me, but I tried here the same code and it does not work

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is that you are having hard time working with dynamic data returned from a server. If this is the case than you need to realise that the typeahead directive works great with the promise API and makes working with async results very easy.

This is an example of a function you could use in your controller:

```
$scope.getUnidades = function($viewValue) {
    return $http.get('Unidades.json').then(function(response){
      return response.data;
    });
  };
```

and then in your markup:

```
 <input typeahead="Unidade.Codigo as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in getUnidades($viewValue)" ng-model="selected" >
```

Here is an example plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/ibIMDNmK26E4mTdDK5dD?p=preview

Comment: It is not working... I don't have the JSON unless I make a query with $http.

Comment: I can't use 'Unidades.JSON' directly

Comment: @UderMoreira this is just an example... you might have this JSON returned from whatever service you can call via $http... Not sure what you mean by `I can't use 'Unidades.JSON' directly`...

Comment: @UderMoreira you are trying to _combine_ my answer with your initial tries. This is not good, you need to use the syntax from answer. Don't add ` | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8` after call to `getUnidades($viewValue)` in your template! Also don't add 2 $http calls.

Comment: In my original it works, but when I select a value from list, the Input value changes to de CODIGO value... I want to NOME remains... I tried everything. I dont know whatelse to do.. still tring here...