# Angular-UI typeahead - Working in v0.04 but not in v0.11

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm essentially trying to the same as in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239989/cant-use-angular-ui-bootstrap-typehead-json-with-multiple-attributes), which was solved with [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Sm17103S73nJbpb2PmK?p=preview).

The goal is to use Angular-UI's typeahead function to set the model to one value, while showing another to the use. This works fine when using ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js, as seen in the plunker. I use ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js in all of my other code, so I'm trying to get it working with that. The issue is that it isn't.

Changing to v0.11, as seen in this plunker, causes it display the same in the model and in the input. (there's also another error that's causing it not to show the options probably, but that does not matter in my case)

Changing the typeahead from:

```
typeahead="Unidade.Codigo as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in Unidades
```

To:

```
typeahead="Unidade as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in Unidades
```

Results in the desired effect, as the input shows the name and the model has the data. It can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/FHqC3HLpkmfQx7VBOGKL?p=preview). My issue is that I would really prefer for the model only to be Unidade.Codigo, as in the first example.

In ideas on how I can achieve this with ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js?

EDIT: Updated the plunker to use AngularJS 1.2.15 as suggested by @mer10z_tech.
Can be seen here - http://plnkr.co/edit/FHqC3HLpkmfQx7VBOGKL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Angular UI bootstrap requires AngularJS 1.2.x, tested with 1.2.10 (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

If you change your Plunker to use AngularJS 1.2.10 it should work.

Comment: I've edited the plunkr to use AngularJS 1.2.15 and the problem persists?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that fixed it but yeah you are right, it still doesn't work correctly. I'm not sure why, maybe this is a bug with Angular.