# angular-ui-typeahead puts modelValue into input's viewValue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

angular 1.3.5, angular-ui-bootstrap 0.12.0

Expressions like

```
typeahead="state.postcode as state.address for state in states | filter:$viewValue"
```

no longer work properly - input's viewValue is always populated with modelValue (state.postcode - instead of state.address in this case)

Fiddle example
http://jsfiddle.net/s7yyv4by/

Do I miss something or is this a bug? It works properly in angular-ui 0.4.0 (see http://jsfiddle.net/dLu0oqn1/)

edit: similar problem: [Angular-UI typeahead - Working in v0.04 but not in v0.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201391/angular-ui-typeahead-working-in-v0-04-but-not-in-v0-11?rq=1)

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is wrong? Cause I am checking your fiddle and every thing seems to be right...

Comment: when you choose 'Manchester' - input with 'typeahead' label should show 'Manchester'- but it shows 'M1' (value which is in model)

Comment: Well currently your typeahead is displaying state.postcode (and you bind that to the model) - hence the 'M1' displayed. Changing the typeahead to `state.address for state in states` displays 'Manchester' as expected.

Comment: @doldt? I bind state.postcode to model, but typeahead input should display state.address ('...as state.address')
I want to have state.postcode in model, but state.address in typeahead input (it works here http://jsfiddle.net/dLu0oqn1/ with angular-ui 0.4.0). With your solution I end up with stater.address in model.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3054

Answer (score 2):

You could approach it this way http://jsfiddle.net/s7yyv4by/2/

Basically set `selPcode` to the entire object. Then access the `postcode` as a property of `selPcode`.

```
postcode <input type="text" ng-model="selPcode.postcode" />
typeahead <input type="text" ng-model="selPcode" typeahead="state as state.address for state in states | filter:{address:$viewValue}" typeahead-editable="false" />
```